# Jquery TypeError: obj is null when passing to handlebars on one item

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I'm having problems with one of my anchors when clicked, it throws `TypeError: obj is null` on a single item. All others work perfectly, there are no differences in the objects that are being passed. In a list of 4 of the same items, there is only one that errors. All `console.logs` show no data that isn't set. I've come to a part where I'm just utterly stuck with debugging.

```
    $('.admin-user-list-click').live('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
        var screen_id = $(this).attr('screen_id');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var last_updated = $(this).attr('updated');
        var last_login = $(this).attr('last_login');
        var user_data = [];
        var template_structure = {logged_in: 'last_login', last_updated: 'last_updated', user_data: user_data, screen_id: screen_id, screen_data: [], identifier: 'screen'};
        var displayContainer = $(this).closest('.admin-page').find('.admin-display');
        $.ajax({
            url: href + '/index/'+user_id,
            success: function(data){
                //Basic user information
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(result, function(k, v) {
                    user_data.push({identifier: k, data: v});
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: href + '/get_user_data/'+user_id,
                    success: function(data){
                        //Question and answers from registeration
                        var decode = $.parseJSON(data);
                        template_structure.screen_data = decode;
                        console.log(displayContainer)
                        console.log(pending_template)
                        console.log(template_structure)
                        console.log(pending_template(template_structure))
                        displayContainer.html(pending_template(template_structure));
                    }
                })

            }// closure of success
        })

}); //closure of click event
```

---

Output of console.log(displayContainer) `[div.admin-display]`

---

Output of console.log(pending_template) `function()`

---

Output of console.log(template_structure) `Object { logged_in= "2012-10-26 08:40:16", user_data=[14], screen_id= "0001", more...}`

---

Output of console.log(pending_template(template_structure)) **shows nothing**

The line in question is on *583 in jquery.1.8.2*

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var name,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length, //this is the line that errors
```

---

When `console.log(obj)` it shows
**When errored**
[image: Jquery logs on errored]

**When it works**
[image: Jquery logs on working]

Comment: Because the data that's being returned is coming from the database and those fields have to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to the handlebar helper I had created

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json_check', function(answer, answer_type) {
    if(answer_type == 'json' && answer !== ''){
        text = '';
        var response = $.parseJSON(answer);
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            text += "<p>"+key+"</p><p>"+value+"</p>";
        });
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(text);
    } else {
        return answer;
    }
});
```

The problem was that at first I wasn't checking if answer was an empty string. So trying to parseJson an empty string threw the error.